# Logging internal server errors by Nginx and Django

Tags: django, nginx, logging

I'm trying to log internal server errors that occur through my django app.

I've set up locations for both access logs and error logs through nginx configuration (`nginx.conf`):

```
http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
...
```

I've simply reloaded nginx after setting this. Every access is logged in `access.log` file without any problems but internal server errors are never logged in `error.log` file, but nginx does have access to it since the only thing that it contains is `[notice] 23802#0: signal process started`).

I have a certain API in my django application that returns json (for Ajax). Unfortunately some internal error has occurred on that certain view (Ajax only logged status code and error name).

---

I think internal server errors are not to be handled by Nginx, Is this true? If so, do I need to manually log internal server errors through Django? (`process_exception()`?). If not, is there something wrong with nginx configuration.

Thank you!

Comment: For a intro to logging take a look at [django docs logging page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/logging/)

Comment: Default behaviour is that with `DEBUG=False` the errors are NOT logged anywhere. You need to change the [`LOGGING` setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-LOGGING) to change that.

Comment: @Ralf Therefore I'm guessing I was right and error logging should be performed by the Django itself correct? `DEBUG` is actually set to true but considering that I'm using Ajax POST requests I'm unable to see the HTML response with error information. I'm guessing I need to add custom `LOGGING` setting or use `process_exception` middleware.

Comment: yes, as far as I know logging has to be performed by Django to get meaningful/useful info (details of the errors) into the logs.